# Extract list values from list of in java

Tags: java-8, java-stream

```
public class FetchVarableList {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    List<List<Employee>> empsList = new ArrayList<>();

    Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "Abi", "Fin", 2000);
    Employee e2 = new Employee(2, "Chandu", "OPs", 5000);
    Employee e3 = new Employee(3, "mahesh", "HR", 8000);
    Employee e4 = new Employee(4, "Suresh", "Main", 1000);
    
    
    List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<>();
    empList.add(e1); empList.add(e2); 

    
    List<Employee> empList2 = new ArrayList<>();
    
    empList2.add(e3); empList2.add(e4);

    
    empsList.add(empList);
    
    empsList.add(empList2);
}
```

}

The code above has a list of employee e1, e2 in `empList` and e3, e4 in `empList2`. These two lists are added to `empslist`. I would like to fetch all employee numbers and store them in a single list of Integers.

How to get the list of employee numbers from `empslist` in Java8?

Comment: What have you tried fo far by the way?

Answer (score 12):

```
List<Integer> numbers = empsList.stream()
                                .flatMap(List::stream)
                                .map(Employee::getNumber)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
List<Integer> numbers = Stream.concat(empList.stream(), empList2.stream())
     .map(Employee::getNumber)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even compile... `empsList2` is not defined. And even when changing to `empList2` it still fails

Comment: There are `empList` and `empList2` variables in question. `empsList2` should be `empList2`

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answer from *JB Nizet* and *ahmet kamaran* you can avoid the step with creating a **list of lists** (`empsList`) by concatenating the 2 lists:

```
List<Integer> numbers = Stream.concat(empList.stream(), empList2.stream())
     .map(Employee::getNumber)
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
```